# Searching in lower-case

Tags: nhibernate.search

I have a two-step search problem. First I want to see if any matches with the exact search-phrase - and then in step 2 take the generic full-text search across a number of properties.

I have mapped the property as follows:

```
[Field(Name = "CompanyNameFull",Index = Index.UnTokenized)]
[Field]
public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
```

My problem is that my users usually search in lowercase - and the company name is usually in proper case. So, "ibm*" doesn't find "IBM International", but "IBM*" does - and "ital*" doesn't find "Italian Furniture" while "Ital*" does.

I've tried in vain to attach an analyzer in the attribute to force it to be lowercase when indexed - but this fails, as the analyzer is only attached if it is a tokenized property (as far as I can tell). I've tried various querying alternatives to no avail either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using a custom tokenizer/analzyer. It isn't exactly ideal, but it should still work.